# Strange statement in if function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I got really strange output from following python function:

```
s = "-8.8373347749999997e-08"
def roundNumb(numb, pos):
    print("roundNumb()", numb , pos)
    ret = ""
    if int(numb[pos]) < 5:
        ret = numb[:pos]
        print("if int(numb[pos]) < 5: ", int(numb[pos]), " ", ret)
    else:
        if int(numb[pos]) == 9:
            ret = roundNumb(numb , pos - 1)
            print("int(numb[pos]) == 9 ", int(numb[pos]), " ",ret)
        else:
            ret = numb[:(pos-1)] + str(int(numb[(pos-1)]) + 1)
            print("else:", ret)
    return ret


>>> roundNumb(s, 12)
roundNumb() -8.8373347749999997e-08 12
roundNumb() -8.8373347749999997e-08 11
if int(numb[pos]) < 5:  4   -8.83733477
int(numb[pos]) == 9  9   -8.83733477
'-8.83733477'
```

as you can see roundNumb function was called twice, but I don't really understand why. It should be ended on first if statement:

```
if int(numb[pos]) < 5:
```

Comment: `"-8.8373347749999997e-08"[12]` is `'9'`

Comment: I don't exactly know what is going on but it may be something to do with the notation, e

Comment: Oops that was meant to be "e-08". Sorry

Comment: The `print` statements are executed after the function recurses. Basically the `print` output is backwards.

Comment: Why not use the builtin round instead of relying on string representation to round your number?

Comment: This is called recursive function, a function which calls itself till a condition is satisfied. If there is no condition to be satisfied. Python will give maximum recursion depth error. There is nothing wrong with the function. It is trying to find to find the string number converted to integer when it will be less than 4 in one if statement and equal to 9 in another if statement.

Comment: @Aran-Fey illustrated what is going on. Thanks. No more replays required.

Answer (score 0):

you call function 
`roundNumb(s, 12) // where numb[pos] = 9`

then function goes to else block 
and execute if block

`if int(numb[pos]) == 9:`

this is the interestin part before this if block execution you call this function again

```
ret = roundNumb(numb , pos - 1) // and herer is function execution pause

print("int(numb[pos]) == 9 ", int(numb[pos]), " ",ret)
```

and then functoin execute if block of your function

```
if int(numb[pos]) < 5:

ret = numb[:pos]

print("if int(numb[pos]) < 5: ", int(numb[pos]), " ", ret)
```

then execute this print function and then that paused function resume 
and then execute this print functon

`print("int(numb[pos]) == 9 ", int(numb[pos]), " ",ret)`

**knowledge about recursion is very helpful to understand this**

Comment: @Aran-Fey illustrated what is going on. Thanks. No more replays required.